# Java Weka get all Instances with given attribute value

Tags: java, machine-learning, attributes, weka

I have an attribute (Using Weka!)

```
@attribute age {10-19,20-29,30-39,40-49,50-59,60-69,70-79,80-89,90-99}
```

How can I get an Instances object of all the data that their value in the attribute `age` is `20-29`?

For example, I have `Instances data` of size 100, and only 10 of those, their value in the attribute `age` is `20-29`, then I want to get an Instances object of those 10 instances.

I couldn't find a descent way to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one answer.

1. Find the `index` of the desired attribute value.
2. loop through dataset and count number of appearances.

code:

```
Instances training = loadData("...");
for(Instance instance: training){
    counter += (int)instance.value(i) == index ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use streams and type deduction, although it'll look a bit unwieldy:

```
int index = training.attribute("age").index();
String nominalToFilter = "20-29";

var filteredInstances = new Instances(training, 0); // Empty Instances with same header
training.parallelStream()
        .filter(instance -> instance.stringValue(index).equals(nominalToFilter))
        .forEachOrdered(filteredInstances::add);
```